# Setting numbers above some value to zero, and then outputting number of non-zeros (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I have data1,data2,...,data20 and I want to set all values above 45 for each of them to zero, and then create n1,n2,...,n20 that contain the number of non-zero values. I've tried this:

```
for i = 1:20
    data{i}(data{i} > 45) = 0;
    n{i} = nnz(data{i});
end
```

It's not working and I can't think of an alternative approach.

Comment: It seems to me like it should work. What problem or error do you get? Paste an example with some data

Comment: it says "Undefined variable "data" or class "data"."     data1,data2 etc are all loaded into the workspace so i dont understand this

Comment: You have `data1`, `data2`, etc. as separate variables, not as a single cell array?

Comment: yes they're separate, is that the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.

Comment: okay thanks. do i have to manually put data1,...,data20 into a single vector?

Comment: That depends.  Is `data1,...data20` vectors? Cell arrays?

Comment: data,...,data20 are single columns of data

Comment: @Gray - I'd concatenate them all into a matrix and work from there.  I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have 20 separate variables and are trying to index them with a loop.  With the way you are trying to access the variables in your loop, you can't because `data` is assumed to be a cell array but you have 20 different variables in your work space... which **aren't** cell arrays.

Having so many variables is usually bad practice, but one thing I'd recommend is if you place all of the variables inside a 2D matrix where each column represents one column of data.  Once you do that, you can simply create a logical matrix out of this data by checking for values that are non-zero and summing up each column individually.  Something like this:

```
data = [data1 data2 data3 data4 data5 data6 data7 data8 data9 data10 ...
        data11 data12 data13 data14 data15 data16 data17 data18 data19 data20];

n = sum(data <= 45, 1);
```

The last line of code is pretty elegant in that we create a `logical` matrix where each value is set to 1 if the corresponding entry is less than or equal to 45 and 0 otherwise and we sum along the columns of this result.

`n` will contain a `1 x 20` vector that sums up the total number of non-zeros for each column, where the `i`th member tells you how many non-zero values were for the `i`th column.

---

However, the above code assumes that each vector has **the same number of elements**.  If this isn't the case, then I would make a cell array that stores all of these together, then loop over each cell and do the same logic:

```
data = {data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6, data7, data8, data9, data10, ...
        data11, data12, data13, data14, data15, data16, data17, data18, data19, data20};

n = zeros(numel(data), 1);
for idx = 1 : numel(data)
    d = data{idx};
    d(d > 45) = 0;
    n(idx) = nnz(d);       
end
```

`n` should still be in the same format as the previous code.

Comment: I would think that at least `n` should be a cell array unless each of `data1..data20` has the same number of non-zero elements.

Comment: @beaker - Why would `n` be a cell array? The OP wants to calculate the number of non-zeros for each cell in the cell array which results in a single number... why wouldn't it be a numeric vector?  A cell array containing a single number for each entry seems superfluous, unless I missed the point completely.

Comment: Oops, you're right... returning nnz, not the actual nonzero entries. My bad :">

Comment: @beaker - lol no problem :)  You probably mixed up `nnz` and `nonzeros`....right?